# Symfony 3 LDAP authentication populate database with all users

Tags: php, authentication, ldap, symfony

I'm trying to implement an authentication system and I'm unsure of the correct way to components to use in the Symfony [security component](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/security.html).

In essence, what I want to do is authenticate users against an LDAP server, but also have access to `User` objects for the purposes of database queries (e.g. listing all users in a dropdown).

Now in the [LDAP tutorial](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/ldap.html) it states:

*Checking a user's password against an LDAP server while fetching user information from another source (database using FOSUserBundle, for example).*

However, it doesn't really go into any explicit detail about how this is done. How can I create `User` objects from the LDAP server? I just want to store `usernames`, `emails`, and `roles` - I don't need passwords since I want to do actual authentication with the LDAP server itself.

Or am I better off to not use `User` entities in a database, and instead grab all the user information from the server whenever someone logs in (so that it's up to date)? If this is the case, how do I fetch this information when someone logs in, and use it in a similar way as I would a set of `User` entity objects?

Comment: for authenticating users via LDAP [this link](http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/ldap.html) looks much detailed. If you are still having trouble may be share some code, error messages etc? For displaying a list of all users you will need to connect and query that yourself as Symfony doesn't have support for that. [this library](https://github.com/ccottet/ldap) seems to be doing it.

Comment: Thanks for the links, I actually linked the first one in my question - it's a touch sparse, but I think if I figure out non-LDAP authentication first I can work my way through it. The second link seems to be exactly what I need to build the initial fixtures, cheers.

Comment: [This bundle](https://github.com/ldaptools/ldaptools-bundle) provides a much more complete LDAP implementation for Symfony (2.3 - 3.0+). I also have an [example config](https://github.com/ldaptools/ldaptools-bundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/LDAP-Authentication-With-The-FOSUserBundle.md) for integration into something like FOSUserBundle, which seems to be the way you're leaning. I also left enough hooks in place for things like auto-creating logged in LDAP users into a separate DB. Also lots of docs on the library it uses [here](https://github.com/ldaptools/ldaptools).

Comment: @ChadSikorra, this looks excellent - thanks so much.